# Monotouch SQLite will this create a new db every time?

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin.ios

I'm a little new to this. I wanted to use the SQLite-net dealio using https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/examples/Stocks/Stocks.cs

That's the exact ecample where I got this code. I like the idea of being able to declare my models super quick and clean.

I got this to run, however. I am wondering if it's going to create a new db and everything every time this runs if you were to call this from the appdelegate class like it suggests.

`new _db = new Database();`

That's what it uses in the app delegate class and I'm a little freaked out by it. I need the data to persist.
Could someone tell me if this will recreate every time, and if so how to create a database, the tables from my model classes and persist them through a normal db file that only gets created once.

Any help is appreciated!

```
public class Database : SQLiteConnection
{
    public Database (string path) : base(path)
    {
        CreateTable<Stock> ();
        CreateTable<Valuation> ();
    }
    // more code here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I messed around with this a bit. The answer is that it will create those tables if they don't exist.

Instead of using `SQLiteConnection` to create the database this way, it's easier to use the `sqliteconnection` and check to see if the database exists. Then, have a method/s that will build out your tables if the db file doesn't exist. There's a code sample below.

This enables you to create all of your classes with an MVC model approach and take advantage of the https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net library while still building the db programmatically without using actual sql statements

```
public class Database
{
    static string documents = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    // I do this so I can access the path without having to create an instance of the datbase class
    public static string db = Path.Combine (documents, "dbAwesome.db");
    static bool exists = File.Exists(db);

    public void GetConnection()
    {
        if (!exists) {
            SqliteConnection.CreateFile (db);
            // Custom methods to create initial tables and values for tables
            CreateMyTables ();
            InsertDefaultValues ();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The CreateTable() method does create the table (if it doesn't already exist), but it won't clobber any data already in the table.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite.Net is an ORM. If you use it (Sqlite.cs) it doesn't re-create tables.

**"Executes a "create table if not exists" on the database"** says method summary.
As you see over code; if execute fails count will be 0 and code pass index creations from existing ORM mapping.

It just looks ORM mapping if it exist behave different as you see below.

It also create indexes for ORM as you know we should use [PrimaryKey]'s. By this way CRUD operations invoke.

```
      /// <summary>
            /// Executes a "create table if not exists" on the database. It also
            /// creates any specified indexes on the columns of the table. It uses
            /// a schema automatically generated from the specified type. You can
            /// later access this schema by calling GetMapping.
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns>
            /// The number of entries added to the database schema.
            /// </returns>
            public int CreateTable<T> ()
            {
                    var ty = typeof(T);

                    if (_tables == null) {
                            _tables = new Dictionary<string, TableMapping> ();
                    }
                    TableMapping map;
                    if (!_tables.TryGetValue (ty.FullName, out map)) {
                            map = GetMapping (ty);
                            _tables.Add (ty.FullName, map);
                    }
                    var query = "create table \"" + map.TableName + "\"(\n";

                    var decls = map.Columns.Select (p => Orm.SqlDecl (p));
                    var decl = string.Join (",\n", decls.ToArray ());
                    query += decl;
                    query += ")";

                    var count = 0;

                    try {
                            Execute (query);
                            count = 1;
                    }
                    catch (SQLiteException) {
                    }

                    if (count == 0) {
                            // Table already exists, migrate it
                            MigrateTable (map);
                    }

                    foreach (var p in map.Columns.Where (x => x.IsIndexed)) {
                            var indexName = map.TableName + "_" + p.Name;
                            var q = string.Format ("create index if not exists \"{0}\" on \"{1}\"(\"{2}\")", indexName, map.TableName, p.Name);
                            count += Execute (q);
                    }

                    return count;
            }
```